# Boxplot whisker don't match the calculated values

Tags: descriptive-statistics, boxplot

Here are my data points:

```
data = [145, 137, 132, 131, 131, 130, 129, 128, 128, 127, 127, 127, 127, 131, 132, 131, 128, 126, 126, 127, 149, 138, 132, 130, 131, 129, 129, 127, 126, 125, 124, 123, 123, 124, 124, 124, 123, 122, 123, 129, 150, 138, 132, 129, 128, 127, 127, 126, 125, 122, 121, 119, 119, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 120, 131, 161, 141, 134, 131, 128, 127, 126, 125, 124, 121, 119, 117, 117, 115, 114, 113, 113, 114, 118, 136, 156, 143, 132, 128, 127, 126, 125, 125, 124, 120, 118, 116, 115, 112, 112, 110, 110, 111, 115, 135, 139, 134, 127, 125, 124, 123, 123, 122, 122, 118, 116, 115, 112, 111, 111, 108, 108, 109, 113, 130, 129, 125, 124, 123, 123, 123, 123, 121, 119, 117, 114, 112, 110, 108, 108, 106, 106, 106, 109, 119, 127, 122, 122, 122, 121, 121, 121, 120, 118, 116, 113, 110, 108, 106, 105, 104, 106, 104, 107, 112, 140, 125, 123, 122, 122, 121, 121, 119, 117, 114, 111, 109, 106, 104, 103, 102, 101, 102, 105, 108, 149, 129, 123, 122, 121, 120, 120, 117, 114, 111, 107, 105, 102, 101, 100, 99, 99, 100, 102, 105, 140, 129, 124, 122, 120, 120, 119, 115, 112, 108, 104, 101, 100, 99, 98, 98, 98, 99, 101, 105, 131, 126, 124, 122, 119, 118, 116, 114, 111, 107, 103, 98, 98, 98, 97, 97, 97, 99, 100, 104, 129, 126, 124, 121, 120, 118, 116, 113, 110, 106, 103, 96, 96, 97, 97, 96, 97, 101, 101, 104, 132, 127, 123, 120, 119, 118, 114, 111, 110, 105, 102, 99, 98, 96, 95, 95, 96, 97, 100, 104, 130, 125, 121, 119, 117, 114, 113, 109, 106, 104, 101, 98, 97, 95, 94, 95, 94, 95, 98, 101, 127, 123, 120, 117, 115, 112, 110, 107, 105, 102, 101, 98, 97, 94, 93, 93, 93, 94, 96, 99, 125, 122, 118, 115, 112, 110, 108, 105, 102, 100, 98, 97, 95, 93, 92, 91, 92, 92, 94, 97, 121, 119, 115, 113, 110, 108, 105, 103, 101, 99, 97, 96, 93, 92, 91, 91, 92, 92, 94, 97, 117, 117, 113, 113, 109, 106, 103, 101, 100, 97, 95, 94, 92, 91, 91, 90, 90, 92, 93, 97, 116, 117, 114, 111, 108, 105, 102, 100, 98, 97, 96, 93, 92, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 93, 97]
```

In python I made a boxplot that looks like this:

[image: box plot]

I also calculated the values of Q1,Q3

```
Q1 , Q3 = np.percentile(data, [25,75])
Q1=101
Q3=123
IQR = 22
Q3+1.5*IQR = 156
Q1-1.5*IQR = 68
```

Q3+1.5IQR matches the whisker of the boxplot, but Q1-1.5IQR does not match it.
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the details of boxplot, probably it is because the minimum value of `data` is 90 so the whisker doesn't go beyond that.

The documentation of R base::boxplot has:

```
range: this determines how far the plot whiskers extend out from the
          box.  If ‘range’ is positive, the whiskers extend to the most
          extreme data point which is no more than ‘range’ times the
          interquartile range from the box. A value of zero causes the
          whiskers to extend to the data extremes.
```

Comment: stackoverflow answered the question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73544151/boxplot-whisker-dont-match-the-calculated-values/73544538?noredirect=1#comment129886666_73544538

Answer is a bit confusting. 
Q1-1.5*IQR = 68 stays the same, but the way boxplot draws the whisker change depending on the data points.

Comment: @Innuendo They say the same thing: the bottom whisker is at the higher of the minimum value or Q1-1.5*IQR and the top whisker at the lower of the maximum value or Q3+1.5*IQR